# Number formatting , JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to format a number. so that the output number has commas at desired locations. but with the help of DecimalFormat library there are commas after every 3 numbers but not able to change get commas after 2 digits after once there have been commas after 3 digits

Output getting - 1,000,000
Required Output= 10,00,000

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class number_comma_applier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat comma = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        double input = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(comma.format(input));
    }
}


type here
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired format with commas after the first two digits and then every three digits, you can customize the format in DecimalFormat more specifically. You can use the character 0 to represent a required digit and # to represent an optional digit. Here's how you can do it:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberCommaApplier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat comma = new DecimalFormat("##,##,###");

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        double input = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(comma.format(input));
    }
}
```

With this format, you will get commas after the first two digits and then every three digits thereafter. For example:

Input: 1000000
Desired Output: 10,00,000
Using the format "##,##,###" in DecimalFormat will allow you to achieve the desired format with commas placed correctly. I hope this helps you